# Tomcat 6.0.28 Unresponsive Because of Blocked Threads During Soak Test

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, garbage-collection, deadlock

We ran several soak tests for our new version of a Java EE web application running on Tomcat 6.0.28 and OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11). The problem occurs in the web tier.

After some time - 50 minutes the first time, 1 hour the second time, and 2.5 hours the third time - one random Tomcat in our clustered web tier stops responding. Looking at the thread dumps we see a large number of threads suddenly blocking.

When the issue occurs the number of threads increases from 93 to 437. 341 of 437 threads are blocked on WebappClassLoader like this:

```
"TP-Processor400" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1ee432e800 nid=0x44d9 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f1ec47c5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006f561a758> (a org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
```

One thread holds the lock:

```
"TP-Processor53" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1ee406f800 nid=0x7cbf runnable [0x00007f1f4545b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:923)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1386)
        - locked <0x00000006f561a758> (a org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
```

Subsequent thread dumps in one minute intervals show that the lock is being released and then obtained by some other thread. After 2 minutes all blocked threads are unblocked, and the server runs fine again.

Deadlock issues with the WebappClassLoader have been reported on the Tomcat bug tracker with applications using their own class loader (https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48694 which is a duplicate of https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48903), which is the case for us as well: Our application is embedded in a clustered OpenCMS installation that uses org.opencms.ocee.base.CmsReloadingClassLoader to load classes.

When the blocking occurs we also see an increase in GC activity from 10% to 50% of CPU time, even though memory and heap don't increase at that time.

Question is what could this blocking be caused by, and what can we do to fix it?

Comment: have you figured out any solution ? My webapp also stops responding after a few requests on tomcat 7.0.42

Comment: It looks like this was addressed in 6.0.33, but I can't find a reference for 7.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the reason for deadlock and the fixes are present in the comment of the bug itself. Check comments of https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48694